# How to decode rootObject

Tags: arrays, xcode, decode, nskeyedarchiver, saving-data

I have a custom class and I am trying to save an array within my class. In the encodeWithCoder method I use the encodeRootObject:theShotArray to save the data. What should I use for the initWithCoder method. There doesn't seem to be a decodeRootObject method. Is there a better way to save an array.

Answer (score 0):

NSArray conforms to the NSCoding protocol, so you can say:

```
NSArray *rootArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithCoder:myKeyedUnarchiver];
```

It may be a little confusing that NSArray's reference page doesn't specifically mention -initWithCoder:, but that's because that method is already described in the NSCoding protocol reference, and the NSArray reference page specifies NSCoding.